# What's computed by this code?

Tags: javascript

An interview question,

What's computed by this code?

```
    (function(n){return (n && n*arguments.callee(n-1)) || 1;})(10);

    a) 10!
    b) Nothing, it's an infinite loop.
    c) 10 to the power of 10
    d) 10!/10
    e) The 10th Fibonacci number.
```

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The output is ``3628800``. But which one is the correct choice here?

Comment: Nothing, it's a syntax error (in strict mode). Or give some wrong answer to make sure you don't get the job at a place that gives interview questions like this.

Comment: I really hope you are not sitting in the interview right now  and posting their questions to [so] ;)

Comment: @torazaburo There is no strict mode and the output is ``3628800``

Comment: @Larabone : `10! = 3628800`. So it's A.

Comment: @Lix No, am just collecting JavaScript interview questions and answers.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Can you explain little more? Actually what is mean by ``10!``?

Comment: @Larabone I don't know what you mean by "there is no strict mode" Perhaps the program is being run by the "node --use_strict" command. Perhaps it is being run in an ES6 environment where strict mode is the default. If you actually want the job, point this out to the interviewer, or at least mention that `arguments.callee` is deprecated, is considered bad practice, and is not necessary.

Comment: @Larabone It's basic mathematics. It's a [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial). `10! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 * 10 = 3628800`

Comment: I didn't know javascript has this weird way of dealing with boolean values.

Comment: @torazaburo As per my knowledge, I have to add "use strict"; in the file or in the function or in the console to opt into strict mode. But here in this code, they are not mentioned it is running in strict mode.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thanks, I was very bad in maths. Now I remember it.

Comment: @torazaburo Can you explain little more? I read the strict mode concept in MDN. You mean the code always run in strict mode for all users?

Answer (score 2):

`a) 10!` meaning the factorial of 10 (mathematical expression for 10 x 9 x 8 x ... x 1)

You can have a guess of the result with the successive calls:

```
(function(n){return (n && n*arguments.callee(n-1)) || 1;})(1);
1
(function(n){return (n && n*arguments.callee(n-1)) || 1;})(2);
2
(function(n){return (n && n*arguments.callee(n-1)) || 1;})(3);
6
(function(n){return (n && n*arguments.callee(n-1)) || 1;})(4);
24
(function(n){return (n && n*arguments.callee(n-1)) || 1;})(5);
120
(function(n){return (n && n*arguments.callee(n-1)) || 1;})(10);
3628800
```

Then if you analyse the code :

- the function returns 1 if the input is 0.
- if the input is greater than 0 it returns the input multiplied the function called with `n-1`.

More precisely, `(n && n*arguments.callee(n-1))` is a boolean operation and it's return value is the last operand evaluated to true, which is the value of `n*arguments.callee(n-1)` each time `n>0`, and 1 instead (thanks to `||1`).

`arguments.callee` is a recursive call in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to analyze recursive calls is to write down a stack of all calls and then evaluate in popping order.

```
[
    10 * (recurse with 10 - 1),
    9 * (recurse with 9 - 1),
    8 * (recurse with 8 - 1),
    7 * (recurse with 7 - 1),
    6 * (recurse with 6 - 1),
    5 * (recurse with 5 - 1),
    4 * (recurse with 4 - 1),
    3 * (recurse with 3 - 1),
    2 * (recurse with 2 - 1),
    1 * (recurse with 1 - 1),
    1 (recursion stops because 0 is falsey, therefore 1 will be returned)
]
```

Then we take the stack and evaluate our way up:

```
[
    10 * 362880 = 3628800,
    ...,
    6 * 120 = 720,
    5 * 24 = 120,
    4 * 6 = 24,
    3 * 2 = 6,
    2 * 1 = 2,
    1 * 1 = 1
    1 = 1 <-- start here then work up
]
```

From this, we can clearly see that the algorithm is `a) 10!`.